# Subclass UILabel and UITextView with common UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uitextview, subclass

I am trying to add a gradient to be background of both a UILabel and a UITextView.  I draw the gradient by overriding the drawRect method in each of the subclasses and adding identical properties to each of the subclasses too.  My question is how to best simplify/combine this code, since both the drawRect method and the additional properties are identical.

It would be great if I could replace/subclass the UIView that both the UILabel and UITextView inherit from.  Then I could change the drawRect code in that common subclass and  add the new properties that UIView subclass as well.  However I don't think this is possible (I would love to be wrong).  I've thought about simplifying the code in the drawRect method so most of it could be called via separate functions, which could be contained in a separate class, but that would still leave the properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not have a proper solution for the properties. But you can avoid duplicate method declarations by making use of Objective-C's [categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that there is actually a solution that allows you to add methods *and* instance variables (properties) to an existing framework class like `UIView`.

You'll need two things:

1. A category. ([Apple Docs: Detailed description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html))
2. Associated objects. ([Good example](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html))

A category enables you to add instance *methods* to an existing class but it *cannot store instance variables i.e. properties*. Luckily there is a work-around for this: You can create a so-called associated object (that is stored externally) and manually declare your getter and setter methods:

**UIView+Background.h**

```
@interface UIView (Background)
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIView *yourProperty;
@end
```

**UIView+Background.m**

```
#import "UIView+Background.h"

NSString *const propertyKey = @"yourPropertyKey";

@implementation UIView (Background)

- (void)setYourProperty:(UIView *)propertyValue {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, propertyKey, propertyValue, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (UIView *)yourProperty {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, propertyKey);
}

@end
```

I haven't tested this yet but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Most views are composited by placing them together in view hierarchies.  Consider making a regular UIView subclass that encapsulates your gradient code, then placing it underneath any sort of view you wish using standard approaches (painting in IB, or addSubview: in code).

From this you get encapsulation without working against the language.

EDIT - To restate, I'm suggestion that you create a view whose only function is to draw a gradient, then *compose* it with other views.  To be clearer about compose, I mean place it underneath other views (make them siblings with matching frames in some parent view, and have the gradient view appear first in z-order -- in the parent's subview array).

```
parent view
  |
  --- gradient view (frame == parent view bounds)
  |
  --- UILabel (frame == parent view bounds, backgroundColor == [UIColor clearColor])
```

The UILabel has all of it's function and as long as you frame it together with the gradient, it will have a gradient background, too.  If you plan to do a lot of reframing, you can certainly create a special UIView subclass for that "parent view" that always frames a gradient behind another (parameter) view like a label or text field or whatever.

Comment: I agree that this would be ideal, but how is it accomplished?  UILabel has a view hierarchy of UIView->UILabel, if I replace UIView with GradientView, how do I add all the functionality of the UILabel class without duplicating all the information of that class.  For UITextView, we would need to duplicate the UIScrollView and the UITextView functionality.  How do I tell the view hierarchy to simply use a different subclass? If I simply add a UILabel as a subview to my GradientView, you've uncoupled the classes, since the GradientLabel is not a subclass of GradientView, but a subview.